# @GeneratedValue ID try to duplicate primary key of entry in existing database MySQL Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring

I've created database of parts in MySQL by importing data from .xlsx file. Last part ID is 3717.

Now I want to insert new record with ID: 3718 into database from my webapp where ID is autogenerated, but the @GeneratedValue annotation tries to generate ID from '1' and then it throws org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException for duplicating primary key.

How do I autogenerate IDs starting from the last part ID in the database?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parts")
public class Part {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String name;
private Integer quantity;
private Double price;

public Part() {}
//getters and setters
```

Comment: Is the id in database AutoIncrement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your hibernate version. Depending on that the generationtyoe.auto will trigger one thing or another.

If what is being used is a table sequence, it is enough with you manually executing sql statement to set current value to your desired one.

If what is being used is an auto_increment table column it is enough altering table to update current increment value.